# css3 ignore nested ULs and LIs

Tags: css

Here's my fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/s44cpc8h/**

Right now the CSS of:

```
#original_items li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
ul li {
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;

    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px #333;
    background-color: #eaa10e;
}
```

is being applied to all the LI's in

```
<ul id="original_items">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3
        <ul class="notMe_items2">
            <li id="notMe">1.2</li>
            <li id="notMe">2.2</li>
            <li id="notMe">3.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="cloned_items"></ul>
```

How do I modify my CSS so that it does not  apply to any nested ULs?
OR
How do I modify my CSS so that it does not  apply to any ULs and LIs with a id/class of "notMe"?

Comment: Remember that IDs have to be unique per document. Having multiple is not right. Change the id to class for `notMe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just write rules to overwrite your existing code.  Add this to your code:

```
.notMe {
float: none;
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 90px;
text-align: left;
border: none;
background-color: gray;
}
```

[JSFiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/s44cpc8h/3/)

Comment: Does not seem to work, I am still getting those boxes :(

Comment: With this method, yes.  Another way to do this though would be to use the CSS :not() selector.  You can learn about that [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/).